# JavaScript regex to extract text and number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am still new on regex (I should learn), I just need JS regex to extract string and number from a text like this: `[number][string]`.

```
( /^(\d+).(\s+)/?)
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can you show some `text` you need to extract from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for '`/\d+[a-z]+/gi`' :

```
var x = "123123K, 333D".match(/\d+[a-z]+/gi); 
console.log(x)​;    //["123123K", "333D"]
```

**UPDATE**: `x` is array. You can iterate over it and extract number and text:

```
xitem.match(/\d+/)[0]      //number
xitem.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0]  //text
```

P.S.: About `\s`:

> Matches a whitespace character, which in ASCII are tab, line feed,
>   form feed, carriage return, and space; in Unicode, also matches
>   no-break spaces, next line, and the variable-width spaces (amongst
>   others).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Examples

Comment: sorry Engineer, I was not clear : for example if I have 123123D I want to extract 123123, and D

Comment: That updated part with two regexes will also match strings like "D123" and "1D1D1"... Makes more sense to capture the two interesting parts: `console.log("123123K".match(/(\d+)([a-z]+)/gi));`.

Comment: your solution dcoder seems to be the union of the two regexp of enginer. thanks to all.

Comment: @DCoder After `/\d+[a-z]+/gi` regexp matching `"D123"` and `"1D1D1"` can't be in matched pieces.All pieces are of `"{number}{text}"` kind.

Answer (score 0):

If the square brackets are in the line as well then do the following:

```
/^\[(\d+)\]\[(\s+)\]$/
```

If they are not

```
/^(\d+)(\s+)$/
```

Comment: I am trying this but x results null:var x = "123123M".match(/^(\d+)(\s+)$/);
  console.log(x);

Comment: `\s` is used to match whitespace. "123123M" doesn't have whitespace.